# How to add a grid of images to a ScrollView in Titanium

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to add rows of two images to a ScrollView in Titanium. I am having a problem in that only one row gets shown.

My Alloy code looks like this:

```html
<Alloy> 
 <Window class='container' statusBarStyle='Ti.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.LIGHT_CONTENT'>
  // Make ios status bar correct color
  <View height='20' top='0' left='0' backgroundColor='#01B6AC'></View>
  <View id = 'savedContents' layout='vertical' top='20'>
  </View>
  <Require type='view' src='bottomBar' id='bottomBar'/>
  <Widget id="fa" src="com.mattmcfarland.fontawesome"/>
 </Window> 
</Alloy>
```

My Controller code looks like this:

```js
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  contentWidth: 'auto',
  contentHeight: 'height',
  showVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
  showHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
  width: '100%',
  height: 400,
  top: 0
});

for  (i=0; i < venueDetails.length; i++) {
  row = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:'100%',
    height:150,
    layout:'composite'
  }); 

  image1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image:'http://www.outnow.io/assets/img/small511by309/'+venueDetails[i]["image1"],
    width:'50%',
    height:150,
    left:0,
    top:0
  });

  row.add(image1);
  if (i+1 < venueDetails.length) { 
    image2 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
      image:'http://www.outnow.io/assets/img/small511by309/'+venueDetails[i+1]["image1"],
      width:'50%',
      height:150,
      left:'50%',
      top:0
    });
    row.add(image2); 
  }
  //$.savedContents.add(row); 
  scrollView.add(row);   
}
$.savedContents.add(scrollView);
```

If I add the row views directly to the $.savedContents view (as per the commented out line in the code above) I see all of the rows correctly (two images per row). If I do this via a createScrollView I only get one row of images. I need to use the scrollView to make the images scrollable.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the layout property has a value `composite`. So the scrollView has the composite layout, so you need to specify the positioning properties or "pins" (top, bottom, left, right and center) for that view (`row`). In your code you only specified the width and height, so all views will be centered in the parent view (ScrollView).

According to [Titanium.UI.View-property-layout Reference](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-layout):

> **composite** (or absolute). Default layout. A child view is positioned
>   based on its positioning properties or "pins" (top, bottom, left,
>   right and center). If no positioning properties are specified, the
>   child is centered.

Comment: Thanks! That sorted it.